# Azure Logic App SQL Connector attribute filter

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am facing the following situation: we use Logic Apps to integrate Dynamics 365 CE (Field Service) with on-premises SQL DB. The "When an item is modified (V2)" trigger is used to synchronize the row updates from the SQL DB to D365. In most of the cases it works fine, however, in one table there is a field which is updated frequently. This leads to trigger the flow unnecessarily.

I know that for "When a record is updated" Common Data Service (now called Dataverse) connector there is the configuration "Filter Attributes" with which you can select the fields to trigger the Logic App. I am looking for a similar solution to the trigger "When an item is modified (V2)". Could you suggest some kind of solution?

Thank you very much,
Laci

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement of the similar feature with "**Filter Attributes**" in "**When a record is updated**"(Common Data Service connector). I'm afraid we can't implement it in "**When an item is modified(V2)**".

We can see the "**Filter Query**" and "**Select Query**" in the drop down list of "**Add new parameter**". But as far as I know, "**Filter Query**" is to filter the record which output from the trigger when update and "**Select Query**" is used to select the fields from record which output from the trigger. So both of them can't implement your requirement.

[image]

For this feature, you can create a ticket on [Azure Feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to ask develop team add this feature.

By the way, if the update table operation is under your control, you can call the logic app when you do update table(on the specified attribute) operation. If so, you need to use "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger)" as the trigger of logic app.